# Is there an efficient way to compute the 2-norm of a matrix-inverse (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

**Context:** I have some theoretical a posteriori error bounds for a two-grid finite-element scheme that I am using for the solution of the buckling eigenvalue problem. However, one of the terms is prohibitively costly to compute and I wonder if I am doing it in a naive way.

**Problem:** Letting A denote the my (sparse) stiffness matrix I compute the Cholesky factorisation:

```
L = chol(A,'lower');
```

I then need to compute the 2-norm of inv(L). I am currently using 'inv' and svds:

```
Linv = inv(L);
LinvNorm = svds(Linv,1);
```

Note that I am using inv as it is in fact the recommended syntax on the Mathworks website: *"For sparse inputs, inv(X) creates a sparse identity matrix and uses backslash, X\speye(size(X))."*

**Question:** This is very slow, of course (especially the computation of the inverse, although svds isn't cheap either). Am I missing a trick here?

**Edit:** I have tried using svds(L,1,0) (to take the reciprocal), but this fails to converge. I am on 2015a so cannot increase the Krylov dimension, which is the recommended fix in newer releases.

Comment: Nothing missing. You are doing an expensive maths operation, it takes time

Comment: @AnderBiguri I had thought as much, I was just being optimistic - a better place to ask may have been Mathematics SE. I will have to try to bound these terms, in that case.

Comment: @Kino You may also want to ask on Computational Science SE: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
LinvNorm = 1 / svds(L, 1, 0)
```

i.e. the reciprocal of the smallest singular value of `L`? (The singular values of the inverse matrix are the reciprocals of the singular values of the original matrix).

Alternative expression are

```
LinvNorm = 1 / sqrt(eigs(A, 1, 0))
```

or

```
LinvNorm = 1 / sqrt(svds(A, 1, 0))
```

which derive from `A == L*L'`.

Comment: Sorry, yes I did try this initially but svds fails to converge in this case. I am on 2015a so cannot increase the dimension of the Krylov space, which is the recommended fix for this in newer releases.

Comment: @kino Did you try to compute `eigs(A,1,0)`? Maybe this is more stable, (and for sure more sparse).

Comment: @kino If the above suggestion, based on elementary linear algebra, is not sufficient, you can try to ask a new question on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ about a better way of estimating your error bounds.